# How has the "Ukraine Democracy Defense Lend-Lease Act of 2022" benefited Ukraine?

Tags: united-states, ukraine, military, foreign-aid

The United States of America has enabled President Biden to offer more help to Ukraine against the Russian aggression through the "**Ukraine Democracy Defense Lend-Lease Act of 2022**":

> In general.--Subject to
> paragraph (2), for fiscal years 2022 and 2023, the President may
> authorize the United States Government to lend or lease defense
> articles to the Government of Ukraine or to governments of
> Eastern European countries impacted by the Russian Federation's
> invasion of Ukraine to help bolster those countries' defense
> capabilities and protect their civilian populations from
> potential invasion or ongoing aggression by the armed forces of
> the Government of the Russian Federation.

1. What deliveries of weapons or military assistance have been made under the said Act to date?
2. What is the cost (in US dollars) of these weapons or military assistance?

Comment: All deliveries were intended to be made within 60 days of the signing of the law, so by sometime during July 2022. Perhaps, you might expand on the question, if this is not sufficient.

Comment: I appears that I made a misstatement in my previous comment. The president was given 60 days to develop and plan for expedited shipment. Given that the provision was known before the law was signed, it seems likely the plan was already in development. Shipments of the equipment would have begun fairly soon after the law was signed. Is the Q about the list of equipment sent or whether all shipments have been completed?

Comment: Mine question what deliveries of weapons and in dollars have already been made under the said Act.